# How to create a new website using ofbiz?

Tags: web-applications, ofbiz

Im new to ofbiz.Tell me How to create a new website using ofbiz for getting the some input from the user and display the message.

Thanks & Regards,
Sivakumar.J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the tutorials

http://www.opensourcestrategies.com/ofbiz/hello_world3.php

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252919/how-to-create-a-cms-web-site-using-ofbiz

Answer (score 1):

Just go though the following site, there you will get the Ofbiz info and also sample application in "ofbiz store" link.

https://sites.google.com/site/ofbizwiki/